# How can I implement street view in flutter with marker in Android to the street view of user current location

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

How can I implement a street view in a Flutter with a marker in Android to the street view of the user's current location?

I have tried some packages but they do not have an option for set-up markers. So I want an alternate method for opening the street view by providing latitude-longitude and set marker.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you can try filing a Feature Request on those packages?